# How to Delete in Linked Lists

Tags: c

I have this code. It deletes the data but it must delete the data one by one showing the user what it deletes. And it must delete from head to tail and tail to head.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
    int data;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

int addnode(node *head, char c){
    node *temp;
        temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=c;
        temp->next=head->next;
        head->next=temp;
        return 0;
}

int deletenode(node *head){
    struct node *x;
    node *prev = head;
    while(prev->next != NULL && prev->next != x)
        prev = prev->next;

    if(prev->next==NULL)
    return;
        prev->next=prev->next->next;
    free(x);
    return;
}

int main(void){

    node head, *current;
    head.next=NULL;
    addnode(&head, 'a');
    addnode(&head, 'b');
    addnode(&head, 'c');

    current=head.next;

    while(1){
        printf("%c", current->data);
        if(current->next == '\0') break;
        current=current->next;
    }

    printf("-%c", deletenode(&head));
    printf("-%c", deletenode(&head));
    printf("-%c", deletenode(&head));

return 0;
}
```

My code only prints:
c b a - - -
Thanks in advance

Comment: `deletenode` does not return anything. Does it even compile?

Comment: your program compiles with warning. You are declaring a struct node, which you haven't defined anywhere (should be either node or struct _node)

Comment: What it is You want to ask actually?
Oh - and the `x` in `deletenode` function seems not initialized...

Comment: @Matso it is not initialized because there is a typo (or a mistake) in the variable type

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to mark a node as 'deleted' in a list, and delete them in one go when necessary. All you need is modify your struct by adding an extra field (e.g. 'int deleted').

Edit:

My wrong here, sorry!

If you want to delete a list from head to tail and tail to head, it's better that your list be doubly linked, i.e. every node must have two pointers with a 'next' pointing to the next node and a 'prev' pointing to the previous node. Otherwise it is not very efficient and convenient to traverse the list in both directions.

In addition, if we mark a node as 'deleted' but not really delete it. We can implement a 'clear list' method which clears the list node by node, not worrying that we might mess up with pointers, especially when the list is being used in the program.

Comment: And when would be _necessary_ then?

Comment: When the program is to be terminated, interrupted, or something.